# Pandas get equivalent positive number

Tags: python, pandas

I have data similar to this

```
data = {'A': [10,20,30,10,-10], 'B': [100,200,300,100,-100], 'C':[1000,2000,3000,1000, -1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

| Index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 1 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |
| 2 | 30 | 300 | 3000 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 4 | -10 | -100 | -1000 |

Here index value 0,3 and 4 are exactly equal but one is negative, so for such scenarios I want a fourth column D to be populated with a value 'Exact opposite' for index value 3 and 4.(Any one value)

Similar to

| Index | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |  |
| 1 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |  |
| 2 | 30 | 300 | 3000 |  |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | Exact opposite |
| 4 | -10 | -100 | -1000 | Exact opposite |

One approach I can think of is by adding a column which adds values of all the columns

```
column_names=['A','B','C']
df['Sum Val'] = df[column_names].sum(axis=1)
```

| Index | A | B | C | Sum val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 1110 |
| 1 | 20 | 200 | 2000 | 2200 |
| 2 | 30 | 300 | 3000 | 3300 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 1110 |
| 4 | -10 | -100 | -1000 | -1110 |

and then check if there are any negative values and try to find out the corresponding equal positive value but could not proceed from there

Any mistakes please pardon.

Comment: The sum value is not 1100 but 1110? Also if different numbers add up to same absolute value, are they still exact opposite or not?

Comment: Yes Richard the sum value is 1110 instead and for second one if different values adds up to same value then it needs to be considered exact opposite

Answer (score 2):

Like this maybe:

```
In [69]: import numpy as np

# Create column 'D' with exact duplicate rows using 'abs'
In [68]: df['D'] = np.where(df.abs().duplicated(keep=False), 'Duplicate', '') 

# If the sum of duplicated rows = 0, this means they are 'exact opposite'
In [78]: if df[df.D.eq('Duplicate')].sum(1).sum() == 0:
    ...:     df.loc[ix, 'D'] = 'Exact Opposite'
    ...: 

In [79]: df
Out[79]: 
    A    B     C               D
0  10  100  1000  Exact Opposite
1  20  200  2000                
2  30  300  3000                
3 -10 -100 -1000  Exact Opposite
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is a slight correction in the problem statement I have updated the question.I can have multiple values in '' Sum Val' having same absolute values. I want to update values for a nearest index

Answer (score 1):

To follow your logic let us just adding `abs` with `groupby` , so the output will return the pair `index` as `list`

```
df.reset_index().groupby(df['Sum Val'].abs())['index'].agg(list)
Out[367]: 
Sum Val
1110    [0, 3]
2220       [1]
3330       [2]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is a slight correction in the problem statement I have updated the question.I can have multiple values in '' Sum Val' having same absolute values. I want to update values for a nearest index

Comment: @sudeah it will be better if you can open a new question ~, since multiple answer were based on your original question ~ :-)

Comment: I have posted another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595779/pandas-get-nearest-index-with-equivalent-positive-number.Could you please help in here still could not find any suitable solution

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': [10, 20, 30, -10], 'B': [100, 200,300, -100], 'C': [1000, 2000, 3000,-1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['total'] = df['total'].apply(lambda x: "Exact opposite" if sum(df['total'] == -1*x) else "")
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is a slight correction in the problem statement I have updated the question.I can have multiple values in '' Sum Val' having same absolute values. I want to update values for a nearest index