# Pandas get nearest index with equivalent positive number

Tags: python, pandas

I have data similar to this

```
data = {'A': [10,20,30,10,-10, 20,-20, 10], 'B': [100,200,300,100,-100, 30,-30,100], 'C':[1000,2000,3000,1000, -1000, 40,-40, 1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

| Index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 1 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |
| 2 | 30 | 300 | 3000 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 4 | -10 | -100 | -1000 |
| 5 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 6 | -20 | -30 | -40 |
| 7 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |

Here sum values  of all the columns for index 0,3,7 equal to 1110 index 4 equals -1110 and sum value of index 5 and 6 equals 90, and -90 these are exact opposite, so for such scenarios I want a fourth column D to be populated with a value 'Exact opposite' for index value 3,4. and 5,6(Nearest index)

Similar to

| Index | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |  |
| 1 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |  |
| 2 | 30 | 300 | 3000 |  |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | Exact opposite |
| 4 | -10 | -100 | -1000 | Exact opposite |
| 5 | 20 | 30 | 40 | Exact opposite |
| 6 | -20 | -30 | -40 | Exact opposite |
| 7 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |  |

One approach I can think of is by adding a column which adds values of all the columns

```
column_names=['A','B','C']
df['Sum Val'] = df[column_names].sum(axis=1)
```

| Index | A | B | C | Sum val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 1110 |
| 1 | 20 | 200 | 2000 | 2200 |
| 2 | 30 | 300 | 3000 | 3300 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 1110 |
| 4 | -10 | -100 | -1000 | -1110 |
| 5 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 90 |
| 6 | -20 | -30 | -40 | -90 |
| 7 | 10 | 100 | 1000 | 1110 |

and then check if there are any negative values and try to find out the corresponding equal positive value but could not proceed from there

Comment: what rule is followed to assign `Exact opposite` only on rows `3` & `4`?

Comment: so value of column Sum val is negative for row 4.I need to find an equivalent positive value which is nearest to this, here it happens to be row 3 so its Exact Opposite

Comment: if row 5 also had values `10, 100, 1000`, what would you do? i don't think your question is fully specified yet.

Comment: Good point, but for this case i need to put Exact opposite to either of row 3 or 5 but not both.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
data = {'A': [10,20,30,10,-10, 30, 10], 'B': [100,200,300,100,-100, 300, 100], 'C':[1000,2000,3000,1000, -1000, 3000, 1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
for i in df.index[:-2]:
    for col in df.columns[0:2]:
        if not df[col][i] == -df[col][i+1]:
            break
    else:
        df.at[i, 'D'] = 'Exact opposite'
        df.at[i+1, 'D'] = 'Exact opposite'
    continue
print(df)
```

This solution only considers 2 adjacent lines.
The following code compares all lines so it also detects lines 0 and 6:

```
data = {'A': [10,20,30,10,-10, 30, 10], 'B': [100,200,300,100,-100, 300, 100], 'C':[1000,2000,3000,1000, -1000, 3000, 1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
for i in df.index:
    for j in df.index[i:]:
        for col in df.columns[0:2]:
            if not df[col][i] == -df[col][j]:
                break
        else:
            df.at[i, 'D'] = 'Exact opposite'
            df.at[j, 'D'] = 'Exact opposite'
        continue
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,your second code is giving following error:ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'Exact opposite'. Not sure if i did a mistake or you are also getting an issue

Comment: @sudeah Sounds like it's trying a typeconversion to long, I don't get an error. I updated the 2nd codeblock, does it work now?